# SVG images not displaying in browser, result of server?

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, svg, server

I'm displaying SVG images with two methods on a website, css background and `<img>` tag, neither of which are working. However, I'm able to load svg files via the `<object>` method, but this doesn't work for this case (it could replace `<img>` but not background images). Because someone will ask, the SVG files are there, and they are accessible if you go to their url directly.

I've been testing and working with this site on a separate, private server and the SVG images were displaying properly there. This leads me to believe that the issue is a result of something server-side.

I've tried adding the following to the .htaccess file, but it didn't fix anything:

```
AddType image/svg xml svg svgz 
AddEncoding gzip svgz
```

I'm aware of some alternative methods that involve httpd.conf, but I don't have access to this.

Here's the troublesome site: http://www.focusvitamins.com/get-started/

Here's the working test site: http://focus.steadfa.st/dtclanding2015/

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
```

as the mime-type for svg images is image/svg+xml. You are missing a +

Comment: Thanks Robert! This fixed the issue, I copy and pasted the code from another source that had the + and somehow it got stripped out, weird. Is there any other way to achieve this? The .htaccess file will get overwritten from time to time as the ecommerce cms updates.